# Selecting rows based on two many-to-many relations

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, many-to-many

I have three tables: `product`, `tag` and `tag_collection` (and two junction tables) (tag collection is a named group of tags)

[image: My table layout]
Now, let's say I have a tag collection named `sugar free cola`, with id: `1`, and it has these tags associated with it: `soda`, `cola`, `sugar free`.

And I have a few products with id's: `4`, `5` and `6`, which have these same tags associated with it.

What query would I have to use to get products `4`, `5` and `6` from tag_collection id `1`.

In other words, how do I get the products that have all the tags that are *also* in a given tag_collection?

I tried a query with `LEFT JOIN` for each table, but this gives me products that have one of the tags in the `tag_collection`.

I am using Postgresql 11.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two junction tables together.  Then aggregate and count the tags:

```
select pt.product_id
from product_tags pt join
     (select tct.*, count(*) over (partition by tct.tag_collection_id) as cnt
      from tag_collection_tag tct 
     ) tct
     on tct.tag_id = pt.tag_id
where tct.tag_collection_id = 1
group by pt.product_id, tct.cnt
having count(*) = tct.cnt  -- number of matches equals the number of tags
```

Comment: @milosa . . . The counting is to ensure that *all* the tags match.